# How can I solve this GCM IncompatibleClassChangeError?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I did nothing but in logcat there is an "IncompatibleClassChangeError".

```
     FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[]
                                          Process:      com.yorgan.ilknurbalcipc.yorgan, PID: 982
                                          java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: The method 'java.io.File android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getNoBackupFilesDir(android.content.Context)' was expected to be of type virtual but instead was found to be of type direct (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd' appears in /data/data/com.yorgan.ilknurbalcipc.yorgan/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.google.android.gms-play-services-gcm-8.4.0_8028f35ea877b98f3f5d34335c02399b7cabc31e-classes.dex)
                                              at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.zzeb(Unknown Source)
                                              at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                              at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                              at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.zza(Unknown Source)
                                              at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                                              at com.yorgan.ilknurbalcipc.yorgan.CARDS.GOOGLE_CLOUD_MESSAGING.GCMRegistrationIntentService.registerGCM(GCMRegistrationIntentService.java:62)
                                              at com.yorgan.ilknurbalcipc.yorgan.CARDS.GOOGLE_CLOUD_MESSAGING.GCMRegistrationIntentService.onHandleIntent(GCMRegistrationIntentService.java:36)
                                              at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:66)
                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                              at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

And my compile sdk version is 24. Also,

```
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha3'
```

I got, versions are incompatible. If compile sdk version is 23, application works. In this case, the application does not work in API 24 devices.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is you have an old version of Google Play Services (8.4.0). Compiling the project with an old version of the library caused the error (where the method may not be static). If you were to compile it again with the updated version (9.4), I believe the problem will go away with no code changes.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your app's build.gradle

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.0'
```

and this in your project's build.gradle

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```